# having trouble getting the div's lined up

Tags: html, css

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cougar Inn Directions</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="case.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="case.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>This is the Cougar Hotel</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="navcon">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li style="border-Left: 1px solid #e9e9e9"><a href="cougarhome.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Cougar Inn </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Accommodations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services/Amenities</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Meeting/Events</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="cougarreservation.html">Reservations</a></li>
                <li><a href="cougardirections.html">Directions</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="contactus.php#phone">Phone</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.php#email">Email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contactus.php#feedback">Feedback</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end navcon -->
    </div>
    <!-- end nav -->
    <div id="pagewrapper">
        <div class="pagecon">
            <h2>This is class pagecon</h2>
            <p>
                <div id="slideshow">
                    <div>
                        <img src="hotel 1 s.jpg" alt="HomePic1">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="hotel 4 s.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <img src="hotel 6 s.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="bodycon">
                    <h1>Directions to</h1>
                    <iframe width="425" height="350"
                        src="https://maps.google.com/maps;output=embed"></iframe>
                </div>
                <!--end bodycon -->

                <table border='1' class="tablecon">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    *From Hwy 37 get off at the Stadium exit and head<br>
                                    east down Broadway to N College Ave.  Turn right on College<br>
                                    onto Bangle Street.  We are right next to Columbia College.
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>
                                        *From I-141 get off at the Hues St exit. Head south<br>
                                        on Hues till you get to Bangle St.  Turn right on Bangle<br>
                                        and you will see the Bangle Inn next to the College.<p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
        <!--end class pagecont -->
    </div>
    <!-- end pagewrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css:

```
 * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#header {
    background-image: url(./headimg.jpg);
    height: 60px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}

#navcon {
    background-image: url(./wood.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: thick;
    border-bottom-color: #083272;
}

#nav {
    width: 450px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    color: #080808;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-size: .9em;
}

    #nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

        #nav ul li {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }

            #nav ul li a {
                border-right: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
                padding: 5px;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                color: #080808;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

                #nav ul li a:hover {
                    background: #144678;
                    color: #fff;
                }

            #nav ul li ul {
                display: none;
            }

            #nav ul li:hover ul {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
            }

                #nav ul li:hover ul li a {
                    display: block;
                    background: #144678;
                    color: #fff;
                    width: 120px;
                    text-align: center;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
                    border-right: none;
                }

                    #nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
                        background: #4879A5;
                        color: #fff;
                    }

body {

background: #B5C4D9;
}

#pagecont {
width: 980px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;

} 

.pagecon {

    background-image: url(./mainbackimg.jpg);
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;

    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.bodycon {

    background: #5F86C0;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
}


.tablecon {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#slideshow {
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    height: 247px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
}

    #slideshow > div {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Im trying to get the boxes to line up so that he pictures are on the left. The "directions to" box should be next to the pictures box and even with it on top. The table should be directly below the pictures box (not do far down).  I have been playing with this for a while and could really use some help.

Comment: Create a fiddle of your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FubSb/

Comment: It should also be noted that this page is (or is suppossed to be, if I did it right) set so that there is no horizontal scroll bar for a screen size of 1024 X 768

Comment: Please post your CSS above, too.

Comment: do you want your table to be below both boxes or just below the picture box ( so the border box is to the right of the table ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I changed your code around a bit. I created a wrapper around your #slideshow div and inserted the table with slideshow into that wrapper to make them a column like so:

```
<div class="left-wrapper"> 
                    <div id="slideshow">
                        <div>
                            <img src="hotel 1 s.jpg" alt="HomePic1">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="hotel 4 s.jpg">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <img src="hotel 6 s.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table border='1' class="tablecon">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p>
                                    *From Hwy 37 get off at the Stadium exit and head<br>
                                    east down Broadway to N College Ave.  Turn right on College<br>
                                    onto Bangle Street.  We are right next to Columbia College.
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>
                                        *From I-141 get off at the Hues St exit. Head south<br>
                                        on Hues till you get to Bangle St.  Turn right on Bangle<br>
                                        and you will see the Bangle Inn next to the College.<p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>        
                </div>
```

Class of that wrapper is  :

```
.left-wrapper {
 display: inline-block;   
}
```

The new css for #slideshow is:

```
#slideshow {
    margin: 10px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    height: 247px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

The new css for .bodycon is :

```
.bodycon {

    background: #5F86C0;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

And findally [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FubSb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `div.bodycon` appears lower than your `div#slideshow` because their `top-margin` settings differ. Set both to an equal number.

http://jsbin.com/yovit/1/

```
.bodycon {
  margin: 10px;
  /* Etc. */
}

#slideshow {
  margin: 10px;
  /* Etc. */
}
```